# How to enable mouse wheel scroll of tabs in gedit?

Tags: gedit, mouse-scroll, tabs, mouse-wheel

In gedit, one used to be able to use the mouse wheel to scroll through all the tabs opened. Now the function is gone. (mouse wheel working very fine, scroll through tabs still working on earlier versions).
Any one knows how to enable, restore or install this very convenient feature?